# Lattice Points in x-y plane

Tags: plane-curves

1. What are Lattice Points?
2. Which points in x-y planes are Lattice Points?

   Is (m,n) a lattice point where m,n are any integers?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not accurate. The points $(m,n)\in\Bbb Z^2$ are **a** lattice, but they are not the **only** lattice in $\Bbb R^2$, consider the sets:

$$\{(a,b\sqrt 2): a,b\in\Bbb Z\},\quad \left\{\left(a+{b\over 2}, b{\sqrt{3}\over 2}\right): a,b\in\Bbb Z\right\}\tag{$*$}$$

These are also a lattices.

Generally a lattice in $\Bbb R^2$ is a $\Bbb Z$ module of rank $2$ which contains a basis for $\Bbb R^2$.

As Cameron notes, this just means that you have integer combinations of two $\Bbb R$-linearly independent vectors from $\Bbb R^2$ (it's important that they be linearly independent over $\Bbb R$ and not something like $\Bbb Q$)

Comment: Or in perhaps friendlier terms: given two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, a lattice is all *integer* linear combinations of these vectors.

Comment: @CameronWilliams This is the best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. The term "lattice points" usually refers to the points with integer coordinates.

Comment: okay thank you for the help.But can i know why?

Comment: does 6x+8y=25 pass through any lattice point?

Comment: @user3481652 why? because that's the definition

Comment: About your $6x+8y=25$: Your book is probably talking about the *integer lattice*, the points with integer coordinates. If $x$ and $y$ are integers, then $6x+8y$ is even, so cannot be $25$. The line does not pass through any points $(x,y)$ of the integer lattice.